# Proving that if $H \cap K = \{e\}$, then $HK = G$ and $G \cong H \times K$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove the following statement.

> Let $G$ be a finite group whose order is a product of two integers $n = ab$. Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$ of orders $a$ and $b$, respectively. Assume that $H \cap K = \{1\}$. Prove that $HK = G$. Is $G$ isomorphic to the product group $H \times K$.

I'm a bit stuck on how to prove this, but here is my attempt.

**Proving $HK = G$**

In general, I don't believe $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, but since it's a subset of $G$, it's enough to show that it has the same size. If that's the case, then as a matter of sets, we have $HK = G$. An element of $HK$ has the form $hk$, so what I want to show is that there are $|H| = a$ choices for $h$ and $|K| = b$ choices for $b$, so $|HK| = ab = n$, which is implied by the intersection of $H$ being trivial. I believe I want to show there is no "overlap." So suppose that $hk = h'k'$ for $h,h' \in H$ and $k,k' \in K$ as an equality in $G$. Then $h^{-1}, k^{-1} \in G$. Multiplying by $k^{-1} h^{-1}$ on the right gives
$$
e = h'k' k^{-1} h^{-1}, 
$$
so $h'k'k^{-1} h^{-1} \in H \cap K = \{e\}$. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

**Isomorphism between $H \times K$ and $G$ **

I don't have any intuition on how to prove, so I'm going to attempt to prove it and see if something goes wrong. The natural map would be
$$
\varphi: H \times K \to G, \; (h,k) \mapsto hk. 
$$
If $\varphi(h,k) = \varphi(h',k')$ implies $hk = h'k'$. If $HK = G$, I believe the above implies that $h = h'$ and $k = k'$, so the map is surjective. As $|H \times K| = |G|$, this implies it is surjective and hence bijective. As for the homomorphism property, for any $(h,k), (h',k') \in H \times K$, we have
\begin{align*} 
\varphi((h,k)(h',k')) &= \varphi((hh', kk')) = (hh')(kk') \\
\varphi((h,k)) &= hk \\
\varphi((h',k')) &= h'k' \\
\varphi((h,k)) \varphi((h',k')) &= (hk)(h'k'). 
\end{align*}
I see no reason that we should have $(hh')(kk') = (hk)(h'k')$ in general, so I believe this property fails.

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to proceed. I'll update this attempt as I work more on this problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904002/redundant-condition-for-internal-direct-product

Comment: Your desired equation  $(hh')(kk')=(hk)(h'k')$ would hold if the group $G$ were abelian. But the smallest nonabelian group, $S_3$, contains subgroups  $H$ and $K$ that form a counterexample to the second question.

Answer (score 3):

Let $k_1, k_2 \in K$ and consider the right cosets $Hk_1, Hk_2$.  Since they are right cosets, either they are disjoint or they are identical.  But the only way they can be identical is if $k_1k_2^{-1} \in H$, and since $K \cap H = \{ 1 \}$, the only way that can happen is if $k_1=k_2$.

Thus, distinct elements of $K$ give rise to distinct (and therefore disjoint) right cosets of $H$.  But then the right cosets of the form $Hk, k \in K$ must exhaust all of the elements of $G$, so $HK=G$.

$G$ need not be a direct product of $H$ and $K$.  All you need is any example where at least one of $H$ and $K$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.  Consider $S_3$ to find one counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

To end your proof of $HK=G,$ simply notice that $hk=h'k'\implies h'^{-1}h=k'k^{-1}\in H\cap K=\{e\}$
$\implies h'=h,k'=k.$

As for the second question " Is $G$ isomorphic to the product group $H \times K$?", the answer is "not necessarily", as shown by @AndreasBlass'counterexample $S_3$ above.